# Expansible card en android

Tags: android

> xml

```
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">



<android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/materialCardView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:minHeight="200dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="230dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Estado2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Apellidos"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/Apellidos"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/Estado2">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nombre2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:text="Nombre"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="21sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Marca2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Marca2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:text="Marca"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="21sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Estado2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nombre2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Estado2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:text="Estado"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="21sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Marca2" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="166dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/profile"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            <com.alespero.expandablecardview.ExpandableCardView
                android:id="@+id/profile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:expandOnClick="true"
                app:inner_view="@layout/activity_home"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view2"
                app:title="Historial">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Estado4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Estado"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="21sp" />


            </com.alespero.expandablecardview.ExpandableCardView>


        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> Adapter

```
**import com.alespero.expandablecardview.ExpandableCardView;**
public class RecycleAdapterUser extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdapterUser.ViewHolder>{

    private ArrayList<String> listasnombre;
    private ArrayList<String> listasmarca;
    private ArrayList<String> listasestado;
    private ArrayList<String> listasestadoeditar;
    private View.OnClickListener lister;


    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView nombre;
        private TextView marca;
        private TextView estado;
        private TextView estado4;
        ExpandableCardView profile;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            nombre=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombre2);
            marca=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Marca2);
            estado=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Estado2);
            estado4=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Estado4);
            profile= itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile);

            profile.setOnExpandedListener(new ExpandableCardView.OnExpandedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onExpandChanged(View v, boolean isExpanded) {

                }
            });
        }

        }



    public RecycleAdapterUser(ArrayList<String> listasnombre, ArrayList<String> listasmarca, ArrayList<String> listasestado, ArrayList<String> listasestadoeditar) {
        this.listasnombre = listasnombre;
        this.listasmarca = listasmarca;
        this.listasestado = listasestado;
        this.listasestadoeditar = listasestadoeditar;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view=LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_adapter,viewGroup,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.nombre.setText(listasnombre.get(i));
        viewHolder.marca.setText(listasmarca.get(i));
        viewHolder.estado.setText(listasestado.get(i));
        viewHolder.estado4.setText(listasestado.get(i));


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listasestado.size();
    }

    }
```

> home

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity implements Response.ErrorListener, Response.Listener<JSONObject> {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;
    JSONArray json2;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    RecycleAdapterUser recycleAdapter;



    ArrayList<String> listasnombre = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> listasmarca = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> listasestado = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> listasestadoeditar = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView2);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String email = intent.getStringExtra("email");

        String url = "http://clientes.midominioprivado.es/Android/Resultados.php?email="+email;
        jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,Home.this,Home.this);
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        Usuario miUsuario = new Usuario();

        json2=response.optJSONArray("DNI");

        JSONObject jsonObject2=null;

        for(int contar=0; contar<json2.length(); contar++){

            try {
                jsonObject2 = json2.getJSONObject(contar);
                miUsuario.setNombre(jsonObject2.optString("Nombre"));
                miUsuario.setApellidos(jsonObject2.optString("Apellidos"));
                miUsuario.setMarca(jsonObject2.optString("Marca"));
                miUsuario.setModelo(jsonObject2.optString("Modelo"));
                miUsuario.setMatricula(jsonObject2.optString("Matricula"));
                miUsuario.setEstado(jsonObject2.optString("Estado"));

                String nombre = jsonObject2.optString("Nombre");
                String apellidos = jsonObject2.optString("Apellidos");
                String marca = jsonObject2.optString("Marca");
                String modelo = jsonObject2.optString("Modelo");
                String matricula = jsonObject2.optString("Matricula");
                String estado = jsonObject2.optString("Estado");

                listasnombre.add(nombre+" "+apellidos);
                listasmarca.add(marca+" "+modelo);
                listasestado.add(estado+" "+matricula);
                listasestadoeditar.add(estado);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        recycleAdapter = new RecycleAdapterUser(listasnombre, listasmarca, listasestado, listasestadoeditar);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recycleAdapter);

    }


}
```

Necesito ayuda, en el adaptador tengo un cardview donde necesito que parte de esa tarjeta sea expandible y al ejecutar me salta el siguiente error
**E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout**
y cuando ejecuto el código se queda con un fondo azul donde no me muestra el textview.

Intento insertar esto : https://github.com/AleSpero/ExpandableCardView entro del cardview.

No sé si hay otras alternativas para realizar un expandible de forma dinámica.
Per en principio me gustaría seguir el estilo que tengo.

Comment: Podrias indicar en que `Actividad` o `Fragmento` estas inicializando el `RecyclerView`

Comment: Desde la clase Home